# How to limit the number of threads created for an asynchronous Seq.map operation in F#?

Tags: multithreading, f#

The current setup goes something like this

```
array
|> Seq.map (fun item -> async { return f item})
|> Async.Parallel
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

The problem is, this tends to create too many threads and crash the application periodically.

How to limit the number of threads in this case (to, say, Environment.ProcessorCount)?

Comment: I'm confused by this. I was under the impression that F# used some kind of thread pool with a processor count limitation already. Not true?

Comment: As Zan mentioned above, I believe Async works with a thread pool that has an upper bound. Are you sure the issue is not within `f`?

Comment: Then the question becomes, can you set the upper bound on the membership of that thread pool manually?

Comment: As far as I know,  the maximum  number is as specified with `System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads`.  I didn't test this assumption, though. (There is only one thread pool per process in .NET.) See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5htx827.aspx

Comment: what's the stack trace of the crash?

Comment: Do: Array.Parallel.map f array instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to parallelize CPU-intensive calculation that takes an array (or any sequence) as an input, then it may be a better idea to use `PSeq` module from the [F# PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/) (which is available only on .NET 4.0 though). It provides a parallel versions of many standard `Array.xyz` functions. For more information, you can also look at [F# translation](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-parallel-samples.aspx) of [Parallel Programming with .NET](http://parallelpatterns.codeplex.com/) samples.

The code to solve your problem would be a bit simpler than using workflows:

```
array |> PSeq.map f
      |> PSeq.toArray
```

Some differences between the two options are:

- **PSeq** is created using Task Parallel Library (TPL) from .NET 4.0, which is optimized for working with a large number of CPU-intensive tasks.
- **Async** is implemented in F# libraries and supports asynchronous (non-blocking) operations such as I/O in the concurrently running operations.

In summary, if you need asynchronous operations (e.g. I/O) then `Async` is the best option. If you have a large number of CPU-intensive tasks, then `PSeq` may be a better choice (on .NET 4.0)

Comment: We have solved it differently, but this is a good answer. Unfortunately, we can't use .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 5):

Since 2018 [pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/pull/6357) there is a built-in option in F# Core via a second overload of `Async.Parallel` [F# doc](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-control-fsharpasync.html#Parallel)

```
array
|> Seq.map (fun item -> async { return f item})
|> fun computations -> Async.Parallel(computations, maxDegreeOfParallelism = 20)
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example of how to do this using a Semaphore, in the spirit of Brian's suggestion:

```
open System

let throttle n fs =
    seq { let n = new Threading.Semaphore(n, n)
          for f in fs ->
              async { let! ok = Async.AwaitWaitHandle(n)
                      let! result = Async.Catch f
                      n.Release() |> ignore
                      return match result with
                             | Choice1Of2 rslt -> rslt
                             | Choice2Of2 exn  -> raise exn
                    }
        }

let f i = async { printfn "start %d" i
                  do! Async.Sleep(2000)
                }
let fs = Seq.init 10 f

fs |> throttle 2 |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously |> ignore
```

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce your own throttle along these lines:

```
let throttle = makeThrottle(8)
array 
|> Seq.map (fun item -> async { do! throttle.Wait()
                                return f item}) 
|> Async.Parallel 
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

`makeThrottle()` would not be too hard to write, but it would incur a little synchronization overhead.  If you are trying to parallelize so many things that you're running out of memory, the throttle overhead is likely to be a non-issue.  (Let me know if you need a sample for this kind of code.)

Finally, if this is really crashing things, it smells like you may be doing something wrong.  The `ThreadPool` typically (but not always) does a good job managing itself.  But in various circumstances, designing your own throttle may be valuable to your app anyway.